# return list based on input argument

Tags: python, list, filter, return, optional-parameters

if any of the input arguments is provided for ex)

> yummy(name="Myeong Tae")`

My output should be

> yummy =[["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"]]

, the function will find the friends whose detail(s) matches the input.

This is my code

```
friends =[["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"],["Tae Hwan","Korea","JeJu"],["Lee Boon Tat","Malaysia","Klang"],["Hong Woo Jin","Korea","Bucheon"],["Kim kyung Tae","Korea","Seoul"],["Michael Jackson","Malaysia","Selangor"],["Son Heung Min","Malaysia","Penang"],["Riu Shan Sil","Korea","Gwang Meoung"],["Paul Kim","Malaysia","Malaca"],["Ki Ryang Park","Korea","Dae Jeon"]]

def yummy(name="", home_country="", home_state=""):
    filtered=friends()
    return filtered




yummy(name="Myeong Tae")
```

i Get an error which says list object is not callable

what am I doing wrong here :(

Comment: `friends()`—you don't need those `()`. `friends` is a list,  not a function.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of this line:

```py
filtered=friends()
```

Here you try to call (using the parentheses) `friends` which is already a list defined like so:

```
friends =[["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"],["Tae Hwan","Korea","JeJu"],["Lee Boon Tat","Malaysia","Klang"],["Hong Woo Jin","Korea","Bucheon"],["Kim kyung Tae","Korea","Seoul"],["Michael Jackson","Malaysia","Selangor"],["Son Heung Min","Malaysia","Penang"],["Riu Shan Sil","Korea","Gwang Meoung"],["Paul Kim","Malaysia","Malaca"],["Ki Ryang Park","Korea","Dae Jeon"]]
```

What you probably wanted to to is:

```py
def yummy(name="", home_country="", home_state=""):
    result = []
    for friend in friends:
        if name in friend or home_country in friend or home_state in friend:
            result.append(friend)
    return result
```

Sample test:

```py
>>> yummy(name="Myeong Tae")
[['Myeong Tae', 'Korea', 'Incheon']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to use `()` in friends, cuz that is not a function. Try this one in function to get result u expected:

```
detail = [x for x in filtered if if name in friend or home_country in friend or home_state in friend]
return  detail
```

Answer (score 0):

Meaby iterrate over the array with the parameter "name" to find the person your looking for? Also arrays are zero-indexed which means the first item of an array is at index 0. In your specific case you will have to iterrate through the persons in the array in order to find a match, like so:

```
for friend in friends:
```

Note that each item (friend) in your array "friends" has an index-position in the array. The first item (friend) in the array is ["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"] and it's lokated at index 0 as arrays are based on zero-index. The same thing applies to the values of each friend, this means that the friends name is located at index 0.

**Values: ["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"]**  - translates to - 
**Indexes: [0,1,2]**

This means that in order to compare the name parameter from method "yummy" with a friend you'll find the friends name like this:

**friend[0]**

```
friends = [["Myeong Tae","Korea","Incheon"],["Tae Hwan","Korea","JeJu"],["Lee Boon Tat","Malaysia","Klang"],["Hong Woo Jin","Korea","Bucheon"],["Kim kyung Tae","Korea","Seoul"],["Michael Jackson","Malaysia","Selangor"],["Son Heung Min","Malaysia","Penang"],["Riu Shan Sil","Korea","Gwang Meoung"],["Paul Kim","Malaysia","Malaca"],["Ki Ryang Park","Korea","Dae Jeon"]]


def yummy(name="", home_country="", home_state=""):
  for friend in friends:
    if name == friend[0]: #friend[0] represents the first item of a friend wich is the name
      return friend #return all items of the friend (name, country, city)         
print(yummy(name="Myeong Tae"))
```

In order to preform actions like this you need to understand loops, if/else statements and operators. I would suggest looking into these things.